# html5 and css3 height of table like the highest of them

Tags: html, css, html-table, row

For example, if I've a table like this:

```
<table>
 <tr>
  <td> lorem ipsum .... </td>
  <td> asd </td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td> lorem ipsum <br<br><br> dolor sit amet .... </td>
  <td> asd 2 </td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td> lorem <br> ipsum .... </td>
  <td> 3asd 3 </td>
 </tr>
</table>
```

I know watching the code and if we want also the test, that the highest row is the "second" where I've put 3 BR tags.
The problem is: If I'd like to have every row with the same height equal to the highest of them, what I've to do?
In this example my second TR is the highest (we can call for example that height "H") and I'd like (without using the height in pixel or something like that, because I have to do it Responsive!) to have every TR = H; But responsive.
Its difficult to explain, I hope you'll understand!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Refer to this.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<title>Example</title>
<style>
table.roundedCorners { 
  border: 1px solid DarkOrange;
  border-radius: 13px; 
  border-spacing: 0;
  }
table.roundedCorners td, 
table.roundedCorners th { 
  border-bottom: 1px solid DarkOrange;
  padding: 10px; 
  }
table.roundedCorners tr:last-child > td {
  border-bottom: none;
}
</style>

<table class="roundedCorners">
  <tr>
    <th>Table Header</th>
    <th>Table Header</th>
    <th>Table Header</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Table cell</td>
    <td>Table cell</td>
    <td>Table cell</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Table cell</td>
    <td>Table cell</td>
    <td>Table cell</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Table cell</td>
    <td>Table cell</td>
    <td>Table cell</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Table cell</td>
    <td>Table cell</td>
    <td>Table cell</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want the other rows to be of the same height as the highest row in the whole table you could just add `<br />` tags to the `<td>`'s that are smaller. HTML can't do it dynamically.

But: you can also use CSS instead. With CSS you can set the height of all rows in a table, or per row.

--CSS can style your whole table--

Something like this should work: (CSS)

```
.yourTableClass td{
    height: 55px; // your desired height
}
```

And if you want to style it PER row, you can do this:

```
.yourClass {
    height: 55px; // your desired height
}
```

Then you add this class to every `<td>` you want to give this height.

Comment: thank you JeroenJK for the answer, but i need it to be RESPONSIVE :) and with pixels isn't responsive.

Comment: I don't know exactly what you mean, but maybe take a look at this: http://css-tricks.com/responsive-data-tables/ Or try using media-queries. :)